# Joomla Module – How to send formdata to a function in helper.php

Tags: php, forms, joomla, joomla3.0

I am working on a small Joomla Module for sending a userinput of an event to database

I stuck at trying to send data from a submitted form to a function in the helper.php file, where I can put the values of the POST into Database.

Can anybody help me out how to achieve that.
Thank you so much

Comment: Please always ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, did not know that ...

Comment: Many people on Stack Overflow do not know about Joomla Stack Exchange.  I see this as a failure in the Stack Exchange Network to promote its niched communities.  I hope to see you registering your account at JSE soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Joomla Ajax Interface for this. Refer to this documentation to learn more - https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface

If you have any further queries related to Joomla! please post at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/